# Comparison of member initialization by constructor vs. direct initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, language-lawyer

I'm creating a class in which one member is a const pointer (immutable address) to another member of the struct.

In the simplified version below, will both classes always behave the same value? Especially in the sense of whether the addresses stored in `ptr` are guaranteed to be properly initialized.

```
struct First
{
  int a;
  int* const ptr = &a;
};

struct Second
{
  int a;
  int* const ptr;

  Second() : ptr(&a) {}
};
```

(In my actual application the member `a` is a class instance, and `ptr` is replaced by a map from some enums to pointers pointing to members of `a`.)

Comment: They have subtle difference about category (about aggregate...). but value of `ptr` is correctly initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the simplified version below, will both structs always behave the same way?

No they won't, but it may be ok for your case. Read on.

Both `First::ptr` and `Second::ptr` will be initialized to the expected value being the address of `First::a` and respectively `Second::a`, but:

> #### [`[class.mem]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#7.sentence-1) & [`[class.mem]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#9.sentence-3)
>
> 7 **In a *member-declarator*, an = immediately following the *declarator* is interpreted as** introducing a *pure-specifier*
>   if the *declarator-id* has function type, otherwise it is interpreted as **introducing a *brace-or-equal-initializer*.**
>
> 9 A *brace-or-equal-initializer* shall appear only in the declaration of a data member. (For static data members,
>   see 12.2.3.2; for non-static data members, see 15.6.2 and 11.6.1). A *brace-or-equal-initializer* for a non-static
>   data member specifies a default member *initializer* for the member, **and shall not directly or indirectly cause
>   the implicit definition of a defaulted default constructor** for the enclosing class or the exception specification
>   of that constructor.

This means, `First` has a defaulted default constructor where `Second` has a user-provided default constructor, which change some characteristic of those classes. I can for instance think of [*aggregates*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr), [*triviality*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#6) and maybe *standard layouts*.

Comment: If I were to add a simple constructor `First() {}`, would that then make them equal or more similar?

Comment: @MortenFyhnAmundsen I think so, yes.